# How to add or reduce the vertical space between lines in the TOC?

Tags: xetex, titletoc, minitoc

I'm using `titletoc` to produce the TOC of the whole book, and using `minitoc` to produce the TOC of each Chapters.

Can I assign some different style to the `subsection` style of book TOC and Chapter TOC?

For example, the line-space between the title the whole book's TOC should be bigger, and the line-space between the title of the Chapter's TOC should be smaller.

How to?

[image]

MWE：

```tex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass[11pt,onecolumn,titlepage,twoside,openany]{book}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{kpfonts}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{tssteelblue}{RGB}{70,130,180}
\definecolor{tsorange}{RGB}{255,138,88}
\definecolor{tsblue}{RGB}{23,74,117}
\RequirePackage{tikz}



% Chapter styling
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter

% Numbered chapters (with minitoc)
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.north west)
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      % Background image
      %\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
           %{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}};
      % Chapter heading
      \draw[anchor=west, inner sep=0pt] (-0.1cm,-1.5cm) node
           [black,
            ultra thick,
            fill=tsorange!10,
            fill opacity=.6,
            inner sep=10pt]
           (0,0)
           {\parbox[t][1.6cm][t]{\paperwidth}
           {\huge\bfseries\sffamily\flushleft\thechapter. #1}};
      % Chapter contents
      \draw[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt] (8.8cm,-7cm) node
           [tssteelblue,
            ultra thick,
            fill=white,
            fill opacity=.8,
            draw=tssteelblue,
            draw opacity=1,
            line width=1.5pt,
            rounded corners,
            inner sep=0pt]
           (0,0)
           {\hspace{1cm}\parbox[t][7.1cm][t]{11cm}
           {\vspace{-1cm}\huge\bfseries\sffamily\flushleft
            \textcolor{black}{\sffamily\minitoc}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{7.5cm}
}

% Unnumbered chapters (without minitoc)
\renewcommand{\@makeschapterhead}[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at (current page.north west)
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      % Background image
      %\node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0)
      %     {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}};
      % Chapter heading
      \draw[anchor=west,inner sep=0pt] (-0.1cm,-1.5cm) node
           [black,
            ultra thick,
            fill=tsorange!10,
            fill opacity=.6,
            inner sep=10pt]
           (0,0)
           {\parbox[t][1.6cm][t]{\paperwidth}
           {\huge\bfseries\sffamily\flushleft #1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{8cm}
}

% Minitoc styling
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{2}
\dominitoc[n]
\nomtcrule
\nomtcpagenumbers
\renewcommand{\mtifont}{\large\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\small\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\small\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\mtcSSfont}{\small\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\mtcSSSfont}{\small\sffamily}

% Table of contents styling
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0cm]
{\addvspace{14pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries}
{\color{tssteelblue}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}{}
{\color{tssteelblue}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries
 \;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}

\titlecontents{section}[0cm]
{\addvspace{6pt}\sffamily\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}}{}
{\sffamily\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage}[]



% Index
\RequirePackage{makeidx}
\makeindex



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is I}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam
nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat
pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent
in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis fringilla tristique
neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi
sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus
tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a, turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc
quis urna dictum turpis accumsan semper.

\section{I-1}

\subsection{I-1-aaa}
\subsection{I-1-bbb}


\section{I-2}

\subsection{title I-2-eee}
\subsection{title I-2-fff}
\subsection{title I-2-ggg}
\subsection{title I-2-hhh}
\subsection{title I-2-iii}

\section{I-3}
\subsection{title I-3-333}
\subsection{title I-3-333}

\section{I-4}
\subsection{title I-4-444}
\subsection{title I-4-444}


\chapter{This is II}


\end{document}
```